# Flutter web build flavor

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

In our flutter app, we rely on build flavors. It works on mobile using

```
flutter build apk --release --flavor dev
```

But when making a flutter web release build, the following is not working

```
flutter build web --release --flavor dev
```

Since build flavor is not supported in flutter web, is there any workaround ? (Environment variables?  Adding more pipeline script steps ? But how ? )

Answer (score 5):

You can use: `var env = String.fromEnvironment("flavor");`

Then, by command line:

```
flutter build web --dart-define=flavor=dev
flutter build web --dart-define=flavor=stg
flutter build web --dart-define=flavor=prod
```

This is the workaround for flutter web.

Comment: Anther approach would be flutter `build web --target='lib/main_stage.dart` etc. and having multiple entry points to the app. Each `main_....dart` could have different predefined environment settings.

Answer (score 2):

command line:

```
flutter build web --release -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

Or

```
flutter build web -t lib/main_dev.dart
```